# Positive integers written as $\binom{w}2+\binom{x}4+\binom{y}6+\binom{z}8$ with $w,x,y,z\in\{2,3,\ldots\}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, additive-combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, integer-sequences

Let $\mathbb N=\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$. Recall that the triangular numbers are those natural numbers
$$T_x=\frac {x(x+1)}2\quad \text{with}\  x\in\mathbb N.$$
As $T_x=\binom{x+1}2$, Gauss' triangular number theorem (first claimed by Fermat) can be restated as follows:
$$\left\{\binom x2+\binom y2+\binom z2:\ x,y,z\in\mathbb N\right\}=\mathbb N.$$

In view of the above, here I pose a conjecture on representations of integers involving binomial coefficients.

**2-4-6-8 Conjecture.** Any positive integer $n$ can be written as 
$$\binom{w}2+\binom{x}4+\binom{y}6+\binom{z}8\quad \text{with}\ w,x,y,z\in\{2,3,\ldots\}.$$

Observe that
$$\frac12+\frac14+\frac16+\frac18=\frac{25}{24}\approx  1.0416667.$$
I have verified the above conjecture for all $n=1,\ldots,3\times10^7$. For example, 
$$4655=\binom{85}2+\binom{14}4+\binom 96+\binom 78=\binom{94}2+\binom 74+\binom 96+\binom{11}8$$
and
$$192080=\binom{7}2+\binom{26}4+\binom{25}6+\binom{9}8=\binom{414}2+\binom{39}4+\binom 86+\binom{17}8.$$
See http://oeis.org/A306477 for related data. Note that $1061619$ is the first positive integer not representable as $\binom w2+\binom x4+\binom y6+\binom z9$ with $w,x,y,z\in\mathbb N$.

> **Question:** Are there references in the literature to this or similar conjectures? What are some possible lines of attack for such problems?

I also have some other similar conjectures. See http://oeis.org/A306460, http://oeis.org/A306462 and http://oeis.org/A306471. For example, I conjecture that $$\left\{\binom{2x}2+\binom y2+\binom z3:\ x,y,z=1,2,3,\ldots\right\}=\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$$
and
$$\left\{2\binom w3+\binom x3+\binom y3+\binom z3:\ w,x,y,z\in\mathbb N\right\}=\mathbb N.$$
The last equality implies Pollock's conjecture which states that any positive integer is the sum of at most five tetrahedral numbers.

Your comments are welcome!

**Edit:** The 2-4-6-8 conjecture has been verified for $n$ up to $5\times10^{11}$ by Yaakov Baruch, and for $n$ up to $2\times10^{11}$ by Max Alekseyev. I'd like to offer 2468 US dollars as the prize for the first correct proof of the 2-4-6-8 conjecture, or 2468 RMB as the prize for the first explicit counterexample.

**Edit (March 12, 2019):** Today Yaakov Baruch reported that he had verified the 2-4-6-8 conjecture for $n$ up to $2\times 10^{12}$ with no counterexample found.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/help/on-topic "MathOverflow is not the right place to ask open problems.... If you want to contribute to (or view) a list of open problems, visit the Open Problem Garden."

Comment: On the contrary, I feel that the present question is perfect for MathOverflow.

Comment: I have verified the conjecture up to $5\times 10^8$.

Comment: Yaakov, thank you very much for your verification! I'd like to call the conjecture "the 2-4-6-8 conjecture".

Comment: A somewhat vague, empiric observation: for the 2-4-6-9 conjecture the only counterexamples up to $2\times 10^8$ are $1061619, 1943709, 2009719, 3024382$ and $3044809$. This makes me think that this conjecture holds for small numbers due to the law of small numbers, and for large ones due to the redundancies caused by $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{9}>1$. Thus, having presumably pushed the check of the 2-4-6-8 conjecture far into its redundancy area, I'd be very surprised if it didn't hold.

Comment: There goes that theory... $226687459$ and $310917242$ are also counterexamples to the 2-3-6-9 (up to $5\times 10^8$).

Comment: @YaakovBaruch Given that the integers below $10^8$ which can be represented in the desired form in only one way are 1, 23343989, 39866594 and 54847142, and given that there are 10, 49, 166, 541 and 1344 numbers below $10^8$ which can be represented in precisely 2, 3, 4, 5, respectively 6 ways, I'd guess that the proposed 2-4-6-8 conjecture is likely false, and that one has quite reasonable chances of finding a counterexample when extending the search bound a bit (say, to $10^{12}$ or so -- perhaps even $10^{10}$ will do, but these estimates are of course speculation).

Comment: As I mentioned, $1/2+1/4+1/6+1/8$ is about $1.04$, just slightly larger than $1$. Thus we should not expect many ways of the required representions for numbers below $10^8$.  Note that the first counterexample to the 2-4-6-9 problem is $1061619$ and the first counterexample to the 2-4-6-10 problem is $68286$. If the 2-4-6-8 conjecture holds for all natural numbers below $10^9$, it should be quite safe. I agree with Yaakov Baruch's analysis. If possible, I hope that Yaakov could extend his verification of the 2-4-6-8 conjecture to $10^9$.

Comment: I got to $1.5\times10^9$ with no counterexamples... but was working in simple miserable awk. Perhaps tomorrow I'll convert to C and push beyond that. As an aside, I didn't always like prior questions from this OP, but I don't think this one deserved the down votes.

Comment: I have verified that the conjecture holds for $n$ below $5\times 10^{10}$.

Comment: @Max Alsekseyev, thank you very much. Your verification result is exciting!

Comment: I've verified the conjecture for $n\leq 2\times 10^{11}$.

Comment: I'm grateful to Prof. Max Alekseyev and Yaakov Baruch for checkng the conjecture. I'd like to offer 2468 US dollars as the prize for the first correct proof of the 2-4-6-8 conjecture.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev: How many integers have you found up to your search bound which can be represented only in 1, 2, 3 or 4 ways in the desired form?

Comment: @StefanKohl: I did not count the number of representations, reserving just one bit for answering whether a number is representable or not. Accounting for the number of representations will multiply the memory usage by a factor, thus reducing the bound I can reach.

Comment: @StefanKohl: In my opinion, all those uniquely represented numbers should be below $10^9$.

Comment: Verified up to $5\times 10^{11}$. That took 58G of memory on a machine with 52G, and 190 minutes, of which 23m system, presumably mostly swapping. So I think I reached my limit. Will be happy to give my code to anyone with better resources.

Comment: @StefanKohl: the list of uniquely represented numbers below $10^{10}$: $0, 23343989, 39866594, 54847142, 394239767, 1769927927, 2321530979$, $5022744494$ and $7969623044$. More than OP was expecting...

Comment: To understand the curious 2-4-6-8 conjecture better, perhaps we should investigate a similar conjecture.  I note that $10413917$ is the least positive integer not representable by $w^2+\binom x4+\binom y6+\binom z8$ with $w,x,y,z\in\mathbb N$. I also guess that each $n=0,1,2,\ldots$ can be written as $w(w+1)+\binom x4+\binom y6+\binom z8$ with $w,x,y,z\in\mathbb N$ (cf. http://oeis.org/A306571). I have verified this new one for $n\le 3\times10^7$, maybe some of you could check it further.

Comment: @Zhi-WeiSun: I checked the latter one a bit further (to $10^8$), and found the counterexample 41215718.

Comment: @YaakovBaruch: This suggests that if the conjecture really happens to be true and one finds a proof with methods from analytic number theory that it holds for sufficiently large numbers, then the bound for "sufficiently large" may well be big enough to turn completing the proof into a challenging computational problem ... .

Comment: @YaakovBaruch  Please note that in my 2-4-6-8 conjecture I require that the number $\binom w2$ is positive, so $0$ should not be considered as a uniquely represented number.

Comment: I think there is almost no hope to find a counterexample. If you can find a concrete example, I may offer 2468 RMB (Chinese dollars).

Comment: That is actually a nice 370$! But I'm waiting for the 3-4-5-6-7 conjecture...

Comment: I think people here focus on math. rather than money!

Comment: Meta discussion: https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4125/publicizing-conjectures-on-mo (I request voting up this comment for visibility). I took the liberty of editing the question to implement some suggestions there.

Comment: @StefanKohl: up to $2\times 10^{12}$ there are no counterexamples, 19 numbers with one representation and 141 with 2. Besides the 10 numbers in my non-answer below, the other 9 with unique rep are: 52640483762, 110740757279, 151955228192, 232115559443, 281156393219, 802140167849, 953628522614, 1331706555617, 1436076907142. Their log-density does not seem to be decreasing, yet. The log-density of the numbers with 2 reps even has a clear concave up shape thus far.

Comment: @Yaakov Baruch   I'm glad to hear that the 2-4-6-8 conjecture holds for $n\le 2\times 10^{12}$. Thank you very much for your verification.

Comment: I really don't think it was necessary to edit (and bump up) the question for just an improved numerical check! In any case, if anything, I think the surprising rate at which numbers with a single representation keep showing up, makes it still quite possible that the conjecture fail for some very large $n$.

Answer (score 13):

2-4-6-8, this we don't appreciate!

There is a long tradition of exploring additive representations of integers by polynomial sequences.  The gold standard for measuring such progress is Waring's problem, but the circle method of Hardy and Littlewood to understand such problems works in many related situations.  In particular, one could use the circle method to flesh out a conjectural asymptotic formula for problems such as the one in this question.  Many of these problems, including the current one, are beyond the reach of current analytic machinery.

To gain a sense of what is feasible, let us return to Waring's problem.  If one wishes to express $n$ as a sum of $s$ $k$-th powers, then if there are no local obstructions one expects this to be possible if $s \ge k+1$.  However the circle method has any hope of working only if $s \ge 2k+1$ -- this is because even if one had square-root cancelation in the exponential sums over minor arcs, then one would need $s>2k$ for the main term to dominate the error terms.  In reality, we are far from this barrier, and one can only prove that $s\ge (1+o(1)) k\log k$ variables suffice.  A key exception is the situation of sums of squares -- plain vanilla circle method needs five variables, the Kloostermann refinement of the circle method allows for sums of four variables, and the connection with modular forms/theta functions allows for three variables.  The case of squares, where we can do better than the limitations of the circle method, is very special.

Now for a variant of Waring's problem more closely connected to the present question.  Roth considered first the problem of writing numbers as the sum of a square, a cube, a fourth power and so on.  Roth established that almost all integers up to $x$ may be written as a sum of a square, a cube and a fourth power.   This is the best possible result of its kind, because $1/2+ 1/3 < 1 < 1/2+ 1/3 +1/4$.   If one asks for all large numbers being represented by an expression of this kind, then the best result known is due to Ford, who showed that all large $n$ are of the form 
$$ 
\sum_{i=2}^{k} x_i^i,  
$$ 
with $k=15$ being permissible. 
To compare this with the limitation on the circle method in Waring's problem mentioned above, the relevant quantity is $1/2+1/3+ \ldots +1/k$, and whether this is $>2$.  It must be clearly be $>1$ for there to be solutions for all large $n$, and square-root cancelation in minor arc exponential sums would solve the problem if the sum of reciprocals exceeds $2$.  This barrier would be crossed at $k=11$, and this gives some rough sense of Ford's work.

The problem here is of the flavor of writing $n$ as 
$$ 
\sum_{i=1}^k x_i^{2i}, 
$$ 
which is even worse than above.  The threshold $\sum_{i=1}^{k} 1/(2i) >2$ is crossed when $k=31$ -- that is, the 2-4-6-8-10-12-...-62 conjecture is the most that circle method aficionados would dream of!

A more reasonable problem would be to ask for almost all integers being represented, in the spirit of Roth.  See work of [Laporta and Wooley](http://archive.numdam.org/article/JTNB_2001__13_1_227_0.pdf) in this (general) context, which will provide further references.

Comment: Is there some general kind of result which says that if $\sum 1/a_k>2$, then sufficiently large integers are of the form $\sum x_k^{a_k}$? I'm afraid I am not well-versed enough in additive number theory to see whether the argument generalizes.

Comment: @Wojowu: No; my point is that one needs the sum to be $>2$ in order to have any hope!  In each situation, what is known would vary depending on our knowledge of the relevant exponential sums.

Comment: I know the limitation of the circle method. If the 2-4-6-8 conjecture could be easily proved by the current circle method without *creative innovation*, I would not  promise $2468 prize for its proof.

Comment: And my point is that you could promise a whole lot more, and it would still be hopeless!  Why not 246810 dollars?  And of course I would expect you to be aware of the circle method -- although the problem gave no indication of this.   Sorry, but conjectures of this type are routine, and you should at least flesh out the main term before stating such a conjecture.

Comment: Number theorists are still interested in the exact value of $G(3)$ in Waring's problem though the circle method even does not work for $G(3)\le6$.

Comment: I'm not sure you've read through my answer.  I point out clearly why the circle method indeed will not give that.  Exactly the point for your conjecture too.  Do you really feel that your conjecture is so different from the Waring problem for unlike powers?

Comment: New methods are usually stimulated by challeging problems which could not be solved by the known methods. There are many interesting open problems which look hopeless to be solved, such as GRH, Schinzel's Hypothesis  and whether there are infinitely many Mersenne primes.

Comment: Yes, indeed.  There are already well established challenging problems to innovate upon.  E.g. in this case Waring's problem, and then (with a significant drop in interest) the Waring problem for unlike powers etc.  I ask again, what do you think is new that we learn from this problem, which we did not know from the circle method?  Why might one expect this to stimulate work, compared to the many problems that workers in the circle method are already familiar with?

Comment: I'm holding this problem to a high standard because the OP is a professional mathematician, and should be aware of the background for such problems.  There are of course a lot of amateurs posing problems on MO.  But from a professional mathematician, I imagine that there is some particular reason that you find this interesting, and I would like to understand what that is.  I am not intending to be offensive, and of course you should feel free to ignore my answer or my comments.

Comment: This problem is particular since $1/2+1/4+1/6+1/8\approx 1.04$. I don't know any conjecture representing *each* $n\in\mathbb N$ as $\sum_{i=1}^k x_i^{a_i}$ with $\sum_{i=1}^k1/a_i<1.04$

Comment: Just take $1/2+1/4+1/6+1/10$ which is a tiny bit more than $1$, and I'm sure you can form some conjecture for large $n$.

Comment: For 2-4-6-10, the first counterexample is 68286. Unlike analytic number theorists, I'm only interested in writing *every* (not sufficiently large)  $n\in\mathbb N$ in a desired form.

Comment: "I'm only interested in writing *every* (not sufficiently large) $n\in\mathbb{N}$ in a desired form". But why? That is the question that several people, including myself, would like to know the answer to. What would it teach you about numbers if you knew that some particular a priori obviously fairly dense set contains all integers, rather than all with, say, one exception?

Comment: I don't want to argue with anyone here. Different people have different viewpoints. For example, if Goldbach's conjecture only holds for even numbers greater than $10^{100}$, it would not be so famous. Usually people like concise results or conjectures.

Answer (score 9):

**Not an answer** - but I decided to delete a prior comment and repost as an answer, because I think it puts the 2-4-6-8 conjecture in a different light than considered so far, hopefully leading to some of the experts providing deeper insights and perhaps even a solution. So the stunning fact (to me) is this:

10 numbers up to $5\times 10^{10}$, besides $0$, were found to have a unique representation; they are $23343989$, $39866594$, $54847142$, $394239767$, $1769927927$, $2321530979$, $5022744494$, $7969623044$, $13295525747$, $14076782201$.

All of them are $\equiv 20\ (\textrm{mod}\ 33)$!

This I think points to a deeper arithmetic nature to the conjecture than it simply (likely) being true for "probabilistic" reasons.

---

**UPDATE.** **I was wrong.** As pointed out in the comments by StefanKohl and user21820, the anomaly described above can be fully explained by the fact that the $\equiv 20\ (\textrm{mod}\ 33)$ residue class appears with only 48.5% of the expected $\frac{1}{33}$ frequency. The next least frequent residue class is $9$, with 64% of the expected frequency.
Since in the ranges considered, every number has more than 50 hits on average, that already makes the single hit probability millions of times higher for class $20$ than class $9$. I verified that also double, triple, etc. hits are quickly dominated by the $20$ residue class, followed far behind by the $9$.

Small upshot: a counterexample is most likely going to be $\equiv 20\ (\textrm{mod}\ 33)$ , and there are low-memory search algorithms that would be faster when restricted to that case. I'll post in the comments if/when I pursue that.

Comment: Please note that in my 2-4-6-8 conjecture I require that the number $\binom w2$ is positive, so 0 should not be considered as a uniquely represented number.

Comment: Truly $0$ should not be regarded as an exception, but less because of your picking a specific requirement, than because if the problem is posed over $\mathbb{Z}$ instead of $\mathbb{N}$, then $0$ has $2\times 4\times 6\times 8$ representations, while the numbers above all have $2^4$ (the minimum possible if the conjecture is true, given that all non-zero values of binomial polynomials $\binom{x}{a}$ have multiplicity $2$).

Comment: See http://oeis.org/A306477 for my definition of the number of representations of $n$.

Comment: The 10 numbers are: $\binom{365}2+\binom{76}4+\binom{40}6+\binom{34}8$,
$\binom{8167}2+\binom{58}4+\binom{43}6+\binom{9}8$,
$\binom{8914}2+\binom{139}4+\binom{26}6+\binom{10}8$,
$\binom{8693}2+\binom{240}4+\binom{43}6+\binom{45}8$,
$\binom{57792}2+\binom{5}4+\binom{67}6+\binom{21}8$,
$\binom{15456}2+\binom{341}4+\binom{93}6+\binom{53}8$,
$\binom{99977}2+\binom{89}4+\binom{41}6+\binom{34}8$,
$\binom{121487}2+\binom{346}4+\binom{39}6+\binom{16}8$,
$\binom{155964}2+\binom{196}4+\binom{90}6+\binom{49}8$,
$\binom{64714}2+\binom{584}4+\binom{134}6+\binom{31}8$. No visible patterns there...

Comment: From congruence conditions, one finds the following relative distribution of the sums $\binom{w}{2}+\binom{x}{4}+\binom{y}{6}+\binom{z}{8}$ over the residue classes modulo 33 (read: 1450/35937 of the sums are congruent to 0 modulo 33, and so on): (to be continued ...)

Comment: (continued:) 1450/35937, 1520/35937, 224/9801, 3364/107811, 460/11979, 248/9801, 3886/107811, 1180/35937, 208/9801, 232/11979, 370/11979, 100/3267, 4408/107811, 1120/35937, 232/9801, 1334/35937, 1240/35937, 268/9801, 3422/107811, 1040/35937, 16/1089, 1073/35937, 500/11979, 304/9801, 3248/107811, 1160/35937, 92/3267, 3596/107811, 1340/35937, 236/9801, 3016/107811, 80/3993, 74/3267. The minimum is at 20 modulo 33 (the value is 16/1089), which statistically explains that numbers having only one representation of the given form are typically congruent to 20 modulo 33.

Comment: Your facts presented in fact suggest the opposite (to your conclusion), namely that there is **no** deep reason for it to be true or false. The probabilistic heuristic and the empirical evidence suggests that the conjecture should be true for sufficiently large $n$. This means that whether or not there are counter-examples is a matter of small number coincidences. The congruence to $20$ mod $33$ should merely be an artifact of the residues of the binomial coefficients mod $33$, which less frequently sum to $20$. (Oh I just realized Stefan Kohl already stated my last point.)

Comment: @Yaakov Baruch  In view of your observation, perhaps one should focus on checking the conjecture with $n\equiv 20\pmod{33}$. For $n>5\times10^{11}$ with $n\equiv20\pmod{33}$, do you have a quick way to check the conjecture for $n$?

Comment: See comments to the original question for an updated search result (not based on any (mod 33) restriction).