# Is it true that $\{x^3-2x+y^3-2y+z^3-2z: x,y,z\in\mathbb Z\}=\mathbb Z$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

A well known conjecture states that
$$\{x^3+y^3+z^3:\ x,y,z\in\mathbb Z\}=\{m\in\mathbb Z:\ m\not\equiv\pm4\pmod 9\}.$$
For $m=33,\, 42$ an integer solution to the equation $x^3+y^3+z^3=m$ was only found last year.

In 2017, Tyrell asked whether
$$\left\{\frac{x(x+1)(x+2)}6+\frac{y(y+1)(y+2)}6+\frac{z(z+1)(z+2)}6:\ x,y,z\in\mathbb Z\right\}=\mathbb Z,$$ see the question with the website http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2472205. Few weeks ago Alkan (cf. [Numbers of the form $x^2(x-1) + y^2(y-1) + z^2(z-1)$ with $x,y,z\in\mathbb Z$](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/366273)) conjectured that
$$\left\{\frac{x^2(x-1)}2+\frac{y^2(y-1)}2+\frac{z^2(z-1)}2:\ x,y,z\in\mathbb Z\right\}=\mathbb Z.$$

I think it's interesting to find a cubic polynomial $P(x)$ with **integer coefficients** such that
$$\{P(x)+P(y)+P(z):\ x,y,z\in\mathbb Z\}=\mathbb Z.$$
This led me to pose the following conjecture.

**Conjecture.** Each $m\in\mathbb Z$ can be written as a sum of three numbers of the form $x^3-2x\ (x\in\mathbb Z)$. In other words, we have
$$\{x^3-2x+y^3-2y+z^3-2z: x,y,z\in\mathbb Z\}=\mathbb Z.$$

As $P(x)=x^3-2x$ is an odd function, the conjecture can be reduced to the case $m\in\mathbb N=\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$. Via computation I found that those natural numbers $n\le1000$ not in the set
$$\{x^3-2x+y^3-2y+z^3-2z:\ x,y,z\in\{-1000,\ldots,1000\}\}$$
are
\begin{gather}70,\ 75,\ 83,\ 86,\ 139,\ 185,\ 198,\ 237,\ 253,\ 262,\ 275,
\ 305,\ 338,\ 355,\ 362,
\\397, 414,\ 415,\ 422,\ 426,\ 457,\ 458,\ 509,\ 535,\ 558,\ 562,\ 564,\ 580,\ 583,
\\  593, \ 613,\ 614,\ 635,\ 642,\ 673,\ 677,\ 684, \ 693,\ 697,\ 722,\ 735,\ 779,\  782,
\\ 790,\ 791,\ 793,\ 807,\ 818,\ 850,\ 851,\ 870,\ 888,\ 898,\ 908,\ 943,\ 957.
\end{gather}
Let $S$ denote the set of these numbers.

**QUESTION**. Can we find an explicit solution of the equation
$$n=x^3-2x+y^3-2y+z^3-2z\ \ (x,y,z\in\mathbb Z)$$ for each $n\in S$?

Comment: Actually I tried $x^2(x-2)$ first, but I  could not verify the representation for all $1\le n\le 40$.  $P(x)=x^3-2x$ is  an odd function, but $x^2(x-2)$ is not and hence less elegant.

Comment: After the computational  reports from C. Wang, Deyi Chen and Tomita,  now it remains to find a required representation for the following 10 numbers: $$185,\ 198,\ 338,\ 422,\ 426,\ 509,\ 558,\ 583,\ 614,\ 793.$$

Comment: @Zhi-Wei-Sun: Solutions for $n=185,198,614,793$ were found.

Comment: @Tomita   Thank you very much for your computational results.

Comment: No solution for $338,422,426,509,558,583$ exists where one of $|x|,|y|,|z|$ does not exceed $6\times10^5$.

Comment: Solutions for n=422,426,509,583 were found.

Comment: $338= P(109043424)+ P(223729659)+ P(-232050701).$
Only $n=558$ remains.

Comment: @Tomita  Great! Hope that you will find a solution for $n=558$ soon.

Comment: Unfortunately, solution for $n=558$ was not found with $|x|,|y|,|z|<10^{10}$.

Comment: I believe each integer can be written as $P(x)+P(y)+P(z)\ (x,y,z\in\mathbb Z)$ in infinitely many ways, where $P(x)=x^3-2x$. Solutions for $P(x)+P(y)+P(z)=0$ with $xyz\not=0$ are also interesting.

Comment: I think it strange that there is no solution for $n = 558$.

Comment: There should be a solution for $n=558$. Maybe the first solution is relatively large, but less than $10^{11}$ in my opinion. Note that the first solution of $33=x^3+y^3+z^3$ given by Booker is particularly large.

Comment: The way solutions appear sporadically, with no small solutions for particular values of $n$, suggests that there is no parametric solution as a function of $n$. I have no idea if it is possible to prove this. If there are no special solutions, then the number of solutions for a given $n$ up to a certain range could follow the "product of local densities" heuristic.

Comment: Comments from a message of Andrew Booker to me: "There is a standard method to search for solutions to $n=P(x)+P(y)+P(z)$ for $P(x)=x^3-2x$, based on the identity $n-P(z)=(x+y)(x^2-xy+y^2-2)$. Running through all candidate values for $z$ and all divisors of the LHS, we extract $x$ and $y$ from the RHS and test whether they are integers. Tomita is surely aware of this, and I assume that's what he is using to conduct his searches."

Comment: More comments from Andrew Booker: "The method as described uses factorization, which is quite slow; it can be made much faster by fixing the divisor $x+y$ and solving the polynomial congruence for $z$, as I did in the case of cubes."

Comment: I already searched the solution of $x^3-2x+y^3-2y+z^3-2z=558$ by solving $z^3-2z\equiv 558 \pmod {x+y}$ with $x+y<10^{10}$.
However my method is not complete.
I assume that $n=x+y=p \times q$ and $p$ is prime number,$q$ is composite number with $p<10^{8}$.
Hence my method does not work when $p>10^{8}$ or $n$ is prime number.

Comment: Since I used the two methods, LLL reduction and solving modulus equation, I'm sure there is no solution for n=558 with $|x|,|y|,|z|<10^{10}$.

Comment: I could not find a solution for $n=558$ using modulus method with $|x|,|y|,|z|<10^{11}$.
To verify this result, I'll use LLL method with PARI-GP, which takes about 20 days.

Comment: @Tomita  Thank you for your great efforts. Hope that you could finally find a solution for $n=558$.

Comment: I finished searching the solution for $n=558$ using LLL method with $|x|,|y|,|z|<10^{11}$.
Unfortunately, the solution for $n=558$ was not found.
I hope someone will find it.

Comment: In a message to me on August 6, 2020, Prof. Andrew Sutherland wrote "If at some point in the future I return to this problem and your question about 558 remains open, I will give it a try (it should be feasible to check for solutions with $\min(|x|,|y|,|z|)$ up to $10^{16}$ without too much effort)."

Answer (score 11):

```
           0 = P(7) + P(10) + P(-11)
             = P(3250) + P(2293) + P(-3593)
             = P(6266) + P(13243) + P(-13695)
             = P(11700) + P(13277) + P(-15797)
             = P(37555) + P(131381) + P(-132396)
             = P(747511) + P(1059490) + P(-1171307)
             = P(5529835) + P(22681597) + P(-22790636)
             = P(8042677) + P(13682243) + P(-14552100)
             = P(14270088) + P(39054467) + P(-39679475)
             = P(29292092) + P(81358953) + P(-82605425)
             = P(42588445) + P(291524359) + P(-291827018)
             = P(56973565) + P(71715599) + P(-82119294)
             = P(35977605) + P(866776048) + P(-866796709)
             = P(143141833) + P(102053460) + P(-158684449)
             = P(784428376) + P(3091918585) + P(-3108657737)
             = P(129810373) + P(136917575) + P(-168147294)

           Though I expanded the search range to 10^10, no solution for n=558 was found.
           On the other hand, there are many solutions for n=1 below.

           1 = P(1439) + P(2554) + P(-2698)
             = P(-1506) + P(-2432) + P(2611)
             = P(-5214) + P(-11006) + P(11383)
             = P(-8516) + P(-17400) + P(18055)
             = P(13952) + P(70243) + P(-70426)
             = P(18457) + P(10233) + P(-19451)
             = P(18949) + P(56163) + P(-56873)
             = P(21394) + P(107636) + P(-107917)
             = P(21599) + P(61917) + P(-62781)
             = P(75215) + P(256620) + P(-258756)
             = P(132479) + P(517316) + P(-520196)
             = P(525599) + P(2589115) + P(-2596315)
             = P(697638) + P(803074) + P(-950033)
             = P(-140064) + P(-198656) + P(219583)
             = P(-198846) + P(-913333) + P(916464)
             = P(-257810) + P(-1509380) + P(1511883)
             = P(-617569) + P(-1930917) + P(1951749)
             = P(-887510) + P(-1092290) + P(1260399)
             = P(-931224) + P(-1288696) + P(1433823)
             = P(1384739) + P(2458622) + P(-2597096)
             = P(1602719) + P(9519294) + P(-9534414)
             = P(4092479) + P(28437689) + P(-28465913)
             = P(4875121) + P(2381859) + P(-5057717)
             = P(9192959) + P(73135432) + P(-73183816)
             = P(-1288696) + P(-931224) + P(1433823)
             = P(-6063625) + P(-20241211) + P(20420995)
             = P(-6919820) + P(-21816096) + P(22045735)
             = P(-8121991) + P(-32025689) + P(32198879)
             = P(18740159) + P(167927031) + P(-168004791)
             = P(24544311) + P(124666228) + P(-124982552)
             = P(62900639) + P(689911189) + P(-690085429)
             = P(96931304) + P(198453683) + P(-205880474)
             = P(-11745176) + P(-17900062) + P(19447931)
             = P(-20241211) + P(-6063625) + P(20420995)
             = P(-24301082) + P(-68349676) + P(69358667)
             = P(-41154429) + P(-47640292) + P(56234034)
             = P(-42083576) + P(-117387233) + P(119163144)
             = P(-95843081) + P(-181052723) + P(189595899)
             = P(106254719) + P(1271978124) + P(-1272225228)
             = P(123437629) + P(177749151) + P(-195715037)
             = P(-119444557) + P(-275690964) + P(282970698)
             = P(-120282709) + P(-113449262) + P(147367664)
             = P(-169017105) + P(-182314167) + P(221641415)
             = P(-181052723) + P(-95843081) + P(189595899)
             = P(-190571214) + P(-1169296181) + P(1170981088)
             = P(-1129360025) + P(-3749403040) + P(3783251348) 

           Solution for n=338 was found using LLL algorithm for X^3+Y^3=1.
           338= P(109043424)+ P(223729659)+ P(-232050701)
           Only n=558 remains.

           Added new solutions.
           422= P(31441077)+ P(52488141)+ P(-56007428)
           426= P(-11575473)+ P(-42374626)+ P(42660619)
           509= P(4620839)+ P(7911642)+ P(-8405584)
           583= P(-2697799)+ P(-3187069)+ P(3732685)


           Added new solutions.
           185=P(-14114372)+ P(-283189)+ P(14114410)
           198=P(-142960)+ P(-613349)+ P(615927)
           614=P(-412307)+ P(-16619)+ P(412316)
           793=P(-296708)+ P(-387970)+ P(438851)  



           262 = P(10239) + P(5400) + P(-10717)
           275 = P(38314) + P(4857) + P(-38340)
           305 = P(8535) + P(5187) + P(-9131)
           355 = P(2568) + P(982) + P(-2615)
           362 = P(6547) + P(636) + P(-6549)
           397 = P(-2029) + P(-973) + P(2101)
           414 = P(1059) + P(576) + P(-1113)
           457 = P(-7709) + P(-6134) + P(8832)
           535 = P(-11999) + P(-2241) + P(12025)
           562 = P(-3435) + P(-862) + P(3453)
           564 = P(-848) + P(-751) + P(1011)
           580 = P(-2295) + P(-825) + P(2330)
           593 = P(1563) + P(458) + P(-1576)
           613 = P(18873) + P(1623) + P(-18877)
           635 = P(10566) + P(9745) + P(-12816)
           642 = P(-5020) + P(-3871) + P(5693)
           673 = P(4487) + P(566) + P(-4490)
           677 = P(5967) + P(1087) + P(-5979)
           684 = P(4316) + P(2750) + P(-4660)
           693 = P(3575) + P(702) + P(-3584)
           697 = P(-17181) + P(-2952) + P(17210)
           722 = P(-1051) + P(-311) + P(1060)
           735 = P(1934) + P(1460) + P(-2179)
           779 = P(3781) + P(1593) + P(-3873)
           790 = P(-152491) + P(-8563) + P(152500)
           791 = P(11265) + P(8599) + P(-12735)
           818 = P(2003) + P(874) + P(-2057)
           850 = P(9047) + P(1510) + P(-9061)
           851 = P(1105) + P(264) + P(-1110)
           870 = P(6390) + P(1917) + P(-6447)
           888 = P(3928) + P(1444) + P(-3992)
           898 = P(1709) + P(929) + P(-1796)
           908 = P(4950) + P(4172) + P(-5788)
           943 = P(-5848) + P(-3743) + P(6320)
           957 = P(-4297) + P(-3091) + P(4775)
```

Answer (score 5):

Let $P(x):=x^3-2x$. Then
\begin{gather}
70=P(2714)+P(1367)+P(-2825),\\
75=P(16333)+P(14200)+P(-19328),\\
83=P(6714)+P(-6682)+P(-1627),\\
86=P(6413)+P(3721)+P(-6806).
\end{gather}

Comment: Dr. Deyi Chen has informed me that he has found $139=P(-105811)+P(105801)+P(6951)$.

Comment: More contributions from Dr. Deyi Chen: \begin{align}237=&P(-54523)+P(54267)+P(13147),\\262=&P(-2719)+P(2712)+P(537),\\275=&P(-38340)+P(38314)+P(4857),\\305=&P(-9131)+P(8535)+P(5187),\\355=&P(-2615)+P(2568)+P(982).\end{align}

Comment: Further contributions from Dr. Deyi Chen: \begin{align}253=&P(-63060)+P(61067)+P(28452),\\415=&P(-80702)+P(79605)+P(27652),\\458=&P(-32329)+P(-12710)+P(32971),\\782=&P(-74024)+P(-56403)+P(83637),\\807=&P(-68697)+P(62165)+P(43789).\end{align}

Comment: This seems inappropriate as an answer; it would be a comment to the question or to the more highly-voted and more informative answer.

Comment: As Deyi Chen is not a user of MO, I just posted his contributions as comments (not an answer) after Wang's answer.

Comment: @MattF., since [this](https://mathoverflow.net/a/366657) one came before the [other](https://mathoverflow.net/a/366670) answer, I think it couldn't reasonably have been a comment on it ….  (But why should it be?)

Comment: @LSpice, because this question now has two upvoted “answers”, when it is not answered at all, not even for a set of positive density.

Comment: @Matt an upvote merely means "this answer is useful".